# Why are these two mapped tuple types not equal?

Tags: typescript, tuples, mapped-types

```
type NumbersTuple = [number, number, number];

type WrapKey<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: { key: T[K] };
};

type WrappedNumbers1 = WrapKey<NumbersTuple>;

type WrappedNumbers2 = {
  [K in keyof NumbersTuple]: { key: NumbersTuple[K] };
};
```

Why are `WrappedNumbers1` and `WrappedNumbers2` not equal? Is it due to how the types are instantiated? I would have expected them to be the same.

Comment: Looks like they changed the behaviour for type parameters, check this PR - https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26063.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is considered a bug in TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#27995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27995) for more information.  When support was added in TypeScript 3.1 for [mapped arrays and tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays), it seems this was only done when mapping over keys of *generic* types like `T` as in your `WrapKey<T>` type  and not when mapping over keys of *specific* types like `Numbers`.

When you map over keys of specific types you will see the old pre-TS-3.1 behavior where *all* properties of arrays are mapped over, including `length` and methods like `push()`, leading to quite bizarre and mostly useless types.  The workaround would involve using an intermediate generic type parameter instead.

If you want to see this fixed you might want to go to that issue and give it a  or describe your use case if you think it is particularly compelling.  It's quite an old issue, though, and it is on [the backlog](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/milestone/29), meaning that it is not slated to be fixed in any upcoming release.  So realistically I wouldn't expect to see it addressed anytime soon.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! Also note - I've edited the code from my question to use the conventional PascalCase