# TypeScript: Wrap function parameters in Promise<T>

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-conversion, mapped-types

I try to create a type that takes a function type, wraps the function parameters in `Promise<>` and returns a new type - the same function but with parameters as Promise, for example:

```
type PromisedFn = PromisedArgs<(a: number, b: string | number) => void>
// should produce (a: Promise<number>, b: Promise<string | number>) => void
```

After hours of racking my brains I only managed to achieve such code:

```
type Func = (id: number, guid: number | string) => number | string; 
type FuncParams = Parameters<Func>;
// FuncParams = [id: string, guid: string | number]

type FuncWrappedParams = {
  [K in keyof FuncParams as Extract<K, '0'|'1'>]: Promise<FuncParams[K]>
}
// { 0: Promise<number>, 1: Promise<string | number> }
```

Still number-indexed object can't be applied as an array properly:

```
type FuncWrappedParamsArray = [...args: FuncWrappedParams[]];
type WrappedParamsFunc = (...args: FuncWrappedParamsArray) => ReturnType<Func>;

let func: WrappedParamsFunc = (
  id: Promise<number>,
  guid: Promise<number | string>
) => 'TestString';

// ERROR:
// Type '(id: Promise<number>, guid: Promise<number | string>) => string'
// is not assignable to type 'WrappedParamsFunc'.
// Types of parameters 'id' and 'args' are incompatible.
// Type 'FuncWrappedParams' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<number>':
// then, catch, [Symbol.toStringTag]
```

I have no idea how to handle this one.

Problem #1 is as above.

Problem #2: the disadvantage is that we must know a number of function parameters ahead of time: `[K in keyof FuncParams as Extract<K, '0'|'1'>]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write `PromisedArgs` like this:

```
type PromisedArgs<T extends (...args: any) => any> =
  T extends (...args: infer A) => infer R ? (
    (...args: { [I in keyof A]: Promise<A[I]> }) => R
  ) : never;
```

As long as your array type is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter (like `A` above), a [mapped type over it will produce another array type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).  In `{[I in keyof A]: ...}`, the key type `I` is essentially only iterating over the numeric-like indices, automatically. You don't have to manually grab `"0" | "1" | "2" | ...` or worry about how to promote the resulting mapped type back into an array.

The use of [the `infer` keyword in the conditional type check](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) is just a way to get both the parameters and return type of the function at once, instead of using  [the `Parameters<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) and [the `ReturnType` utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) separately.  If you look at the definitions [of `Parameters`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/f12922c8f76755944024de2fa83557f573294972/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1526) and [of `ReturnType`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/f12922c8f76755944024de2fa83557f573294972/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1536) you'll see that they are implemented the same way.

Anyway, let's make sure this works as intended:

```
type Func = (id: number, guid: number | string) => number | string;
type WrappedParamsFunc = PromisedArgs<Func>
/* type WrappedParamsFunc =
   (id: Promise<number>, guid: Promise<string | number>) => string | number */

let func: WrappedParamsFunc = (
  id: Promise<number>,
  guid: Promise<number | string>
) => 'TestString';
```

Looks good!

---

By the way, there's an bug in TypeScript, reported at [microsoft/TypeScript#27995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27995), which might have prevented you from finding this solution yourself.  It turns out to be important that you are mapping over the keys of an arraylike *generic type parameter*.  If you try to map over a specific type, the mapping will fallback to iterating over all of the keys, even the array methods and stuff:

```
type Foo = [1, 2, 3]
type Bar = { [I in keyof Foo]: Promise<Foo[I]> }; 
/* type Bar = {
    [x: number]: Promise<3 | 1 | 2>;
    0: Promise<1>;
    1: Promise<2>;
    2: Promise<3>;
    length: Promise<3>;
    toString: Promise<() => string>; 
    ...
*/
```

Since `Foo` is a specific type and not a type parameter, you get the mess above. Your `FuncParams` is a specific type like `Foo`, and you tried to clean up the mess manually, which didn't quite work.  Oh well!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: So because of the bug, *any* time I want to produce an array type from another array type, I need that conditional trick, right? (That's indeed where I was stuck -- and as you say, I think the OP as well -- when I was trying to solve this yesterday.) Do you know if we have a clean "How do I create a new array type from an array type?" question with that as an answer? I couldn't find one yesterday.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder well, there's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66429203/why-are-these-two-mapped-tuple-types-not-equal but I don't know if that fits your criterion